# apache connection was reset while the page was loading on windows 2008 server

Tags: windows, apache, server

I'm running a php script in windows 2008 server using xampp server, the script works normaly until I check some pages,it start loading I get this error in firefox :

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a
>   few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your
>   computer's network connection. If your computer or network is
>   protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted
>   to access the Web

.

When I check the php logs I get nothing, in apache logs I always find this after getting the problem:

```
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:02.076599 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00428: Parent: child process 3048 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.144999 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.878199 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.878199 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.878199 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.909399 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3736
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:10.157399 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3736:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:10.469399 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3736:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:10.609799 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3736:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I disabled the firewall, I change the port, I increase memory limit, without any result.
I do a backup of the script and I moved it to my laptop running with windows 7, the problem disapear and the script sart working normaly.

So is this problem causes by apache? and how I can fix it?